# How to instantiate a nib into view without a viewcontroller as owner?

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, xctest

I have a subclass of a UICollectionViewCell that I want to unit test just on it's own. How can I instantiate it (is it possible?) on its own without an owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. In this code, I will assume that your cell class name is: `CustomCollectionViewCell` and it is located in `CustomCollectionViewCell.xib` files:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for:CustomCollectionViewCell.self)
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell", bundle: bundle)
//nibName should be the same as your file name
let cell = nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil).first as? CustomCollectionViewCell
```